ndarray add to a part of an array
I am trying to add to a part of an ndarray, however, my current approach:
fn test() {
    let a = nd::array![
        [ 1, 2, 3 ],
        [ 4, 5, 6 ],
    ];
    let b = nd::array![
        [ 3, 2, 1], 
        [ 6, 5, 4],
    ];

    println!("{}", a.slice_mut(nd::s![0, ..]) + b.slice(nd::s![0, ..]));

    // desired outcome 
    // a = [
    //     [ 4, 4, 4 ],
    //     [ 6, 5, 4 ],
    // ];
}

This doesn't compile:
error[E0369]: cannot add `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&{integer}>, _>` to `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&mut {integer}>, _>`
  --> src/main.rs:27:49
   |
27 |     println!("{:?}", a.slice_mut(nd::s![0, ..]) + b.slice(nd::s![0, ..]))
   |                      -------------------------- ^ ---------------------- ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&{integer}>, _>
   |                      |
   |                      ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&mut {integer}>, _>

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0369`.

How can I do what I'm trying to do here?

As far as I can tell, you can't use + to update a mutable view. But you can use += on them.
let mut slice = a.slice_mut(nd::s![0, ..]);
slice += &b.slice(nd::s![0, ..]);
println!("{}", slice); // [4, 4, 4]

If you don't need slice, it can be written in one line:
*&mut a.slice_mut(nd::s![0, ..]) += &b.slice(nd::s![0, ..]);

Then the original array will be as you expect.
println!("{}", a);
// [[4, 4, 4],
//  [4, 5, 6]]


Just checked and yes you can, just for some reason the slice needs to be asigned to a variable first e.g. your let mut slice = a.slice_mut(nd::s![0, ..]); slice += &b.slice(nd::s![0, ..]); works but a.slice_mut(nd::s![0, ..]) += &b.slice(nd::s![0, ..]); doesn't. Out of curiosity do you know why this is the case and/or if there is a more succinct syntax for this?

@Pioneer_11 This is mostly a limitation of rust syntax in that you can't have function calls on the left side of an assignment. If you want it in one line, you can use the add_assign method directly. But that still doesn't return anything. You can always make your own function.

thanks, I'm not massively bothered about the length I was just surprised as I've generally found rust's syntax to be pretty intuitive and terse and this isn't

Actually you're allowed any arbitrary code, but only when the end result is being dereferenced. I'll add this to the answer.
